# CSS Styling and HTML

Tags: css

Why can I not only use `.container` class to style the images when images are under the container class? When to use .class and when tag?

CSS code:

```
.container{
   display: inline-flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
}

img {
   width: 350px;
   height: 300px;
   margin: 10px;
   /*transition: all 2s;*/
   transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
 }
```

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <h1>Life in The Wild.</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/52500/horse-herd-fog-nature-52500.jpeg">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/66898/elephant-cub-tsavo-kenya-66898.jpeg">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/213399/pexels-photo-213399.jpeg">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/158471/ibis-bird-red-animals-158471.jpeg">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/133459/pexels-photo-133459.jpeg">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/50988/ape-berber-monkeys-mammal-affchen-50988.jpeg">
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You should get some CSS basics first https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS. It is fine to be lazy as a programmer, but don't take it too far.

Comment: Refer this artical for understand css difference between class and id https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
.container{
      display: inline-flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
}
.container img{
      width: 350px;
      height: 300px;
      margin: 10px;
      /*transition: all 2s;*/
      transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  }
```

```html
  <body>
    <h1>Life in The Wild.</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/52500/horse-herd-fog-nature-52500.jpeg">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/66898/elephant-cub-tsavo-kenya-66898.jpeg">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/213399/pexels-photo-213399.jpeg">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/158471/ibis-bird-red-animals-158471.jpeg">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/133459/pexels-photo-133459.jpeg">
        <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/50988/ape-berber-monkeys-mammal-affchen-50988.jpeg">
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Please provide more information/explanation about how this is solving the question.

Comment: you're right, I didn't think you were a beginner. Thanks for your warning. after that I will try more instructive in my answers

Comment: Slow down there, Turbo. It's not for me, it's for other people who might be brought to this question and answer. And it wasn't a warning either. Just a suggestion as to how you can make your answers more complete. The OP asked two questions, neither of which you answered. You just said "try this".

Answer (score 0):

You can style the img tags using the container selector since they are nested in your html

The selector for that in css is `.container img { /*your img css here*/}`. I assume you are just starting out but using a preprocessor like less or sass is good for styling nested elements and classes like this. The advantage of using classes is to have more control and specificity over your styling. For instance you might not want to style all your images the same way so you would add a class to them and then use that selector in css to add the specific styling you want.